# Is handler.removeCallbacks(runnable) is equivalant to thred's exit

Tags: android, multithreading

Say I write:

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.e(TAG, "runnable entered");
        // working
        Log.e(TAG, "runnable completed");
    }
};

Thread t = new Thread(runnable);
t.start();
```

After `t.start();` we will get the log message **runnable entered**.
While working will threads I always want that my runnable gets completed & after completion my application will not anymore work on this thread.
i.e. I should always get this log **runnable completed**;

Now suppose I use Handler instead of Thread class.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.post(runnable);
```

Can I be sure that the `handler.removeCallbacks(runnable)` is like runnable is completed and my application will not work on this runnable anymore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`handler.removeCallbacks(runnable)` removes the pending `Runnables` from the message queue. But doesn't stop the currently running Runnable. For example say you have a Runnable of A

```
class A implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        handler.removeCallbacks(a);
        Log.i("tag", "are start");
                    // Do work
        Log.i("tag", "end");
    }
}

A a = new A();
```

and you called

`handler.post(a);`

So when the first runnable execute it will call the `removeCallbacks` method. But in the logcat you will see that the output will be

> start
>
> end

while if you don't use `removeCallbacks` in the `run` method then the output will be

> start
>
> end
>
> start
>
> end